# Is there any overhead difference between a pointer and reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Is there any performance difference between passing a pointer and passing a variable by reference? I'm assuming internally they're both using pointers but was wondering if there are any minor differences.

E.g

```
int v = 5;
```

by pointer

```
void MyFunc(int* P);
MyFunc(&v);
```

or by reference

```
void MyFunc(int& R);
MyFunc(v);
```

Comment: Why don't you check the produced assembly to be sure? No, there is no difference.

Comment: You'd have to disassemble the code, standard says nothing about how references are implemented. I would tend to assume references are implemented as pointers and use them to prevent potentially unnecessary overhead in your function implementation i.e. `if(ptr)`.

Comment: `int *p = 5;` would be a terribly bad idea ... `p` is now pointing at address 5 ...

Comment: Also in your example, both `MyFunc` calls take a pointer.

Comment: That really depends on your compiler.   Theoretically, there is nothing stopping a compiler from passing references and pointers using different mechanisms.   Practically, I've yet to come across a compiler that represents them differently in machine code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both methods will have comparable performance.

Pointers and references are syntactically different but they are identical in terms of runtime performance and generated code in most of the time.